# Subsets of the Mandelbrot set

Tags: complex-numbers, fractals, complex-dynamics

In order to define the Mandelbrot set $\mathbb M$, one looks at the sequences
$$
s = f(0),(f\circ f)(0), (f\circ f \circ f)(0),\ldots,
$$
where $f:\mathbb C \to \mathbb C,~z\mapsto z^2+c$ for different $c\in\mathbb C$. Now if $c$ is such that the resulting sequence $s$ is bounded, then $c\in\mathbb M$, otherwise $c\notin \mathbb M$. Does anyone know if there are characterizations or (even better) visualizations of the following related sets? I'd be grateful for a reference.

$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbb M_\ell & :=\{c\in \mathbb C, s\text{ is a periodic sequence with period $\ell$.}\}\\
\mathbb M_p & := \bigcup_{\ell \in \mathbb N}\mathbb M_{\ell}\\
\mathbb M_{np} & := \mathbb M\setminus \mathbb M_p\\
\mathbb M_{\text{con}} & := \{c \in \mathbb C, s\text{ converges.}\}
\end{aligned}$$

Answer (score 0):

- The sets $M_l$ are finite (they have $2^l$ elements). They are "in the center" of the connected components of the interior of the Mandelbrot set, and are not on its boundary.
- The set $M_p$ is therefore countable, consisting of points all in the interior of $M$; but its closure contains the boundary of $M$.
- $M_{np}$ is too big to have a simple description: after all, you only removed countably many points from $M$.
- Presumably, $M_{con}$ is exactly the interior of the main cardioid (plus the parameter $c=\frac{1}{4}$, together with a countable collection of points corresponding to parameters for which the sequence $s$ is eventually constant. Those countable parameters are located at certain tips on the boundary of the Mandelbrot set.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Could you please explain how you find the cardinality of $M_l$ and what the reason for your guess for $M_{con}$ is?

Comment: https://www.mrob.com/pub/muency/enumerationoffeatures.html $f_c^p(0) = 0$ is a degree $2^{p-1}$ polynomial in $c$ so it has $2^{p -1}$ roots.  Some of these roots may have a lower period too, maybe you want to count them in only one $M_l$ (with $l$ as low as possible).  I'm not sure how to take into account potential multiplicity of the roots.